# Deploy Nuxtjs SSR to VPS with ubuntu 20.04.2 and Apache 2.4.53

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vps

I have a VPS with ubuntu 20.04.2 and Apache 2.4.53 installed and I want to deploy a Nuxt SSR application to it with pm2 or any other possible way. I have followed the deployment guides like [this official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/pm2) and others. The problem is when I open my domain in the browser nothing shows without giving any errors.

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'cup',  
    exec_mode: 'fork',  
    instances: '1',  
    script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',  
    args:"start"
  },],

  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: 'SSH_USERNAME',
      host: 'SSH_HOSTMACHINE',
      ref: 'origin/master',
      repo: 'GIT_REPOSITORY',
      path: 'DESTINATION_PATH',
      'pre-deploy-local': '',
      'post-deploy': 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
      'pre-setup': ''
    }
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --hostname my.domain.com --port 3020",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1648802546.c9880dc",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-qrcode-reader": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4"
  },
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": "3020"
    }
  }
}
```

`npm run dev` on the server throws this error

```
 FATAL  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.domain.com                                                                    06:29:22

  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                        │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                   │
   │                                                        │
   │   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my.domain.com.          │
   │                                                        │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

However, `npm run start` works and runs the process on `https://my.ip:3020/`.
but when I open it in the browser nothing shows. And, Also, I want to hide the port because I don't want my users to manually type the port every time they visit my app.

Comment: Do you use SSG, SSR or SPA for your app? You need to build/generate it before running `start`.

Comment: @kissu I'm using the default which should be SSR. and yes I build before start.

Comment: `3020` is a used port already apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers For debugging purposes, maybe try with the regular 80/443 port. Then you could change that one afterwards.

Comment: @kissu I tried 80 and 443 but it says permission denied and tested with 3000 but the issue is the same

Comment: `it says permission denied`, probably a nice place to start.

Comment: like how? could you please be more specific? I'm really not good with servers

Comment: Not sure, further investigation needs to be done on the server by reading the logs and by reading their documentation since it's specific to a PM2 process here IMO. You can always pay for an Heroku/Render.com/alike instance if you're not good with servers.